# Preview an audio file before Post

Tags: php, jquery, html, audio

I am new here apologies for any anomalies, The task I've been given is to create an image/audio file upload or link page with preview before POST.

Not sure how late I am but just discovered Html5 audio tag, I'd like to know how to preview an audio file on selection before upload.

here's my upload form:

```
<form id="attach" action="imageUpload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            <h2>Select An Audio File to Upload</h2>
            <br>
            <div>

            <input type='file' id="files" name="files" multiple onchange="previewAudio(this);" />
            <br>
            <br>
            <output id="list"></output>
            <ul>
                <li>
            <label for="caption">Caption</label>
            <input type="text" maxlength="30"  name="caption" id="caption" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <textarea id="desc" name="desc" rows="4" cols="32">Description

                    </textarea>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <audio controls>                    
                <source id="test3" src="" type="audio/mpeg">
                Your browser does not support the audio element.
            </audio>               
            <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
            </div>
        </form>
```

here is the code I've been playing with tryin to get it to preview:

```
function previewAudio(input)
    {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#test3').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }

    }
```

I'm most adamant that this should work but its not, any fixes or new methods will be highly appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks JWarner that link was a nice starting point, learnt a lot in my almost 5 hours researching this and ended up finding a solution here [Reading files in JavaScript using the File APIs](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

here is how I did it:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
 document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change',  handleFileSelect,false);
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

  // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
   for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

  // Only process image files.

  if (f.type.match('image.*')) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
 alert('e.target.result');
  // Closure to capture the file information.
  reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
    return function(e) {
      // Render thumbnail.

      var span = document.createElement('span');

      span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                        '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '" width="230"    height="270"/>'].join('');
      document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);

    };
  })(f);
  }else if (f.type.match('audio.*')){
  var reader = new FileReader();

  // Closure to capture the file information.
  reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
    return function(e) {
      // Render thumbnail.

      var span = document.createElement('span');

    span.innerHTML = ['<audio controls><source src="', e.target.result,'   "type="audio/ogg"><source src="', e.target.result,' "type="audio/mpeg"></audio>'].join('');
      document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);

    };
  })(f);
}
  // Read in the image file as a data URL.
  reader.readAsDataURL(f);
}
  } }, false);
```

Please point out any weak points in this code if there are any
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.quackit.com/html/html_music_code.cfm) is something that *may* help you, allowing you to circumvent the use of Java and make use of bare HTML instead.

I also hope it doesn't insult you to point out that, I'm not sure there's a way to just "preview" a song, and that you may have to host shortened versions of the song that serve as preview-length, for your scripts to play, rather than having the code automatically truncate them.